# Solr server not available on: https://localhost:8983/solr/

Tags: unix, solr

I am new to Solr. I have a large csv file in my hdfs location and I am trying to index it using Apache  Solr. But it throws out an error. Below is the command I am using.

`hadoop jar jobjar/connectors/plugins/lucid.hadoop/hadoop-job/hadoop-lws-job-2.0.0-rc2-0.jar com.lucidworks.hadoop.ingest.IngestJob -Dlww.commit.on.close=true -DcsvFieldMapping=0=id,1=text -cls com.lucidworks.hadoop.ingest.CSVIngestMapper -c hdp1 -i /tmp/neethu/solr/mydata.csv -of com.lucidworks.hadoop.io.LWMapRedOutputFormat -s https://localhost:8983/solr/`

Error message is :

`SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
15/03/12 15:52:27 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.map.tasks.speculative.execution is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.map.speculative 
Solr server not available on: https://localhost:8983/solr/`

I am unable to view the solr admin page whenever i copy paste the url https://localhost:8983/solr/ in my browser. It says `This webpage is not available` and I think this could be the reason that I am getting the above error.Could any one tell me why I am unable to view the solr admin page on my browser. I tried a lot on this.

Comment: how have you started the SOLR server?

Comment: yes i have started the SOLR server. Is it due to some security reasons on the laptop that I am unable to view the solr admin page ?

Comment: Do the Solr log give any useful errors? How are you starting Solr?

Comment: java -jar start.jar. It says solr server not available on: https://localhost:8983/solr/

Comment: and what do you see on the shell after starting the server? Does it throw any error?

Comment: No it do not throw any error while startup . Only problem here is that I am unable to view the solr admin page on my browser

Comment: Do you have the slf4j jars in the lib/ext directory? Specifically, slf4j-api-1.7.6.jar and slf4j-log4j12-17.6.jar. Also, are there any other errors that appear in solr.log, or just this one?

Comment: i reinstalled solr in another system, now that error is resolved.